# Depedency errors during React app build with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite

I've migrated an app to React 18 / Router v6 and `vite build` results in these errors:

```bash
node_modules/@types/react-router-dom/index.d.ts:13:10 - error TS2305: Module '"react-router"' has no exported member 'match'.

13 import { match } from 'react-router';
            ~~~~~

node_modules/@types/react-router-dom/index.d.ts:19:5 - error TS2305: Module '"react-router"' has no exported member 'PromptProps'.

19     PromptProps,
       ~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/@types/react-router-dom/index.d.ts:20:5 - error TS2305: Module '"react-router"' has no exported member 'Prompt'.

20     Prompt,
       ~~~~~~

node_modules/@types/react-router-dom/index.d.ts:23:5 - error TS2305: Module '"react-router"' has no exported member 'RedirectProps'.

23     RedirectProps,
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/@types/react-router-dom/index.d.ts:24:5 - error TS2724: '"react-router"' has no exported member named 'Redirect'. Did you mean 'redirect'?

24     Redirect,
       ~~~~~~~~

node_modules/@types/react-router-dom/index.d.ts:25:5 - error TS2305: Module '"react-router"' has no exported member 'RouteChildrenProps'.

25     RouteChildrenProps,
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/@types/react-router-dom/index.d.ts:26:5 - error TS2305: Module '"react-router"' has no exported member 'RouteComponentProps'.

26     RouteComponentProps,
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/@types/react-router-dom/index.d.ts:31:5 - error TS2305: Module '"react-router"' has no exported member 'StaticRouterProps'.

31     StaticRouterProps,
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/@types/react-router-dom/index.d.ts:32:5 - error TS2305: Module '"react-router"' has no exported member 'StaticRouter'.

32     StaticRouter,
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/@types/react-router-dom/index.d.ts:33:5 - error TS2305: Module '"react-router"' has no exported member 'SwitchProps'.

33     SwitchProps,
       ~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/@types/react-router-dom/index.d.ts:34:5 - error TS2305: Module '"react-router"' has no exported member 'Switch'.

34     Switch,
       ~~~~~~

node_modules/@types/react-router-dom/index.d.ts:35:5 - error TS2305: Module '"react-router"' has no exported member 'match'.

35     match,
       ~~~~~

node_modules/@types/react-router-dom/index.d.ts:37:5 - error TS2305: Module '"react-router"' has no exported member 'withRouter'.

37     withRouter,
       ~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/@types/react-router-dom/index.d.ts:38:5 - error TS2305: Module '"react-router"' has no exported member 'RouterChildContext'.

38     RouterChildContext,
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/@types/react-router-dom/index.d.ts:39:5 - error TS2305: Module '"react-router"' has no exported member 'useHistory'.

39     useHistory,
       ~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/@types/react-router-dom/index.d.ts:42:5 - error TS2724: '"react-router"' has no exported member named 'useRouteMatch'. Did you mean 'RouteMatch'?

42     useRouteMatch,
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/@types/react-router-hash-link/index.d.ts:19:18 - error TS2320: Interface 'NavHashLinkProps' cannot simultaneously extend types 'NavLinkProps' and 'Omit<HashLinkProps, "style" | "className">'.
  Named property 'children' of types 'NavLinkProps' and 'Omit<HashLinkProps, "style" | "className">' are not identical.

19 export interface NavHashLinkProps extends NavLinkProps, Omit<HashLinkProps, 'className' | 'style'> { }
```

This seems to be caused by this dependency in `yarn.lock`:

```
"@types/react-router-dom@^5.3.0":
  version "5.3.3"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@types/react-router-dom/-/react-router-dom-5.3.3.tgz#e9d6b4a66fcdbd651a5f106c2656a30088cc1e83"
  integrity sha512-kpqnYK4wcdm5UaWI3fLcELopqLrHgLqNsdpHauzlQktfkHL3npOSwtj1Uz9oKBAzs7lFtVkV8j83voAz2D8fhw==
  dependencies:
    "@types/history" "^4.7.11"
    "@types/react" "*"
    "@types/react-router" "*"

"@types/react-router-hash-link@^2.4.6":
  version "2.4.6"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@types/react-router-hash-link/-/react-router-hash-link-2.4.6.tgz#6411fb185e126bb1b985c6867a0e413670082f34"
  integrity sha512-JOV4Q1N60tJJUPisS/u1jiXn8c4jX7ThQf8XavzZYIWOIv0RP17nbyI9YgEZh1r3APXpP9ZkU1ytrlv+1+8jcw==
  dependencies:
    "@types/history" "^4.7.11"
    "@types/react" "*"
    "@types/react-router-dom" "^5.3.0"
```

Is there something I can do about it?

There's no newer version of `react-router-hash-link` with updated type definitions for `react-router-dom`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this to `tsconfig.json` fixed it - maybe there are better solutions?

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}
```